# How can I replace all instances of a string in my entire home directory?

Tags: posix

I am working on a library, and I made a major change. All my projects import `github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/src/...`, but I have shortened my projects to `github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/...`. I need to find every occurrence of it starting at `~`, and replace all occurrences. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is your friend.

```
$ sed -i 's_github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/src_github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils_g' *.txt
```

Where `*.txt` is whatever text files you want to search/replace. Note that the `_` is important. It's used to separate the patterns in the search-and-replace, because you have both the standard `/` separator and the oft-used alternative `-` in your pattern. The `-i.bak` option will tell `sed` to edit the files in place, and save a backup copy with the extension `.bak`.

If the files are in many subdirectories, you'll need to use a combo like `find` and `xargs`.

```
$ find ~ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's_github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/src_github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils_g'
```

Again, `*.txt` is whatever regex will find only those files you want to replace text in.

**DISCLAIMER**: As with anything involving these tools, you should try this out on something replaceable or in a new git branch first.

EDIT: Removed extension on `-i` flag. As pointed out in the comments, everything is under source control, so it should be fine to do in-place editing without saving a backup file.

Comment: My files are all `.go`, not `.txt`. Will it still work?

Comment: Sure, just use `find ~ -name "*.go" ...` instead

Comment: So whatever repo I run this command in, it will recursively look for it in the repos inside of it - and files within those repos?

Comment: Yes, `find` will recursively walk the file hierarchy, and `xargs` takes all of those files found and runs the `sed` command on them.

Comment: way to remove all `.bak` files? Then I will accept.

Comment: `find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 rm`. (Careful with this one.)

Comment: Under git, I would use  `sed -i` rather than `sed -i.bak`. The files are already in source control, so you don't need backup files, and the '.bak' files will just clutter the repository.

Comment: Don't use the ~ in the find line !!! It will apply the change to your whole home dir!

Comment: @timthelion Yes...That's exactly what the OP asked for: *I need to find every occurrence of it starting at `~`*. If you accidentally edited files under your home, that's because you didn't realize what this would do, not because the solution doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what "starting at ~" means with regards to git. But `find ~ -name "*.txt" -print0` searches your entire home directory and has NOTHING to do with git.

Comment: @bnaecker Sorry, I now see that I had miss understood the question.

Comment: @bnaecker see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375758/how-do-i-cancel-an-edit-before-it-is-peer-reviewed

Answer (score 1):

This command finds all the files in your home directory, minus the ones in your `.git` folders:

```
find ~ -type d -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -print
```

To replace all instances of something with something else, we can use sed:

```
sed 's|\(github\.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/\)src/|\1|g' filename
```

This captures the part we want to keep and uses it in the substitution.

Combining these commands to go through all your files, using the `-i` flag for in-place editing (use `-i ''` for BSD sed / Mac OS) – we replace the `-print` action with `-exec sed`:

```
find ~ -type d -name '.git' -prune -o -type f \
-exec sed 's|\(github\.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/\)src/|\1|g' {} \;
```

Comment: @mklement0 Aargh, I did have that in my last version when testing, but didn't transfer it. `-type f` is also required in the first version, because the default behaviour is apparently to AND the whole expression with `-print`.

Comment: Indeed (from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)): "if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries `-exec`, `-ok`, or `-print`, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by: `( given_expression ) -print`" (with an implied `-a[nd]` between `)` and `-print`). That means that you don't strictly need the `-print` at the end.

Comment: @mklement0 Without `-print`, it lists directories not named `.git`.

Comment: You're absolutely right (I assume you meant that it prints directories that _are_ named  `.git` as well): an _implied_ `-print` would amount to `find . \( -type d  -name '.git' -prune -o  -type f \) -print`, which, when encountering a `.git` dir, _would_ print it, because `-prune` always evaluates to true. By contrast, your (correct) command is equivalent to `find . \( -type d  -name '.git' -prune \) -o  \( -type f -print \)`, which, due to the presence of an _explicit_ `-print`, does _not_ apply an implicit one in the `-prune` branch.